# Ros2 launch gives an error in ros2_control_demos

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I am trying ros2_contro_demos.

Follow the tutorial,

```
git clone -b galactic https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control
git clone -b galactic https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers
git clone -b galactic https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos
```

and

```
 rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y
 colcon build --symlink-install
```

I have finished to build with some additional packages.

But, I hit

```
ros2 launch rrbot_description view_robot.launch.py
```

I get an error below

```
raise SubstitutionFailure("executable '{}' not found on the PATH".format(self.name))
launch.substitutions.substitution_failure.SubstitutionFailure: executable '[<launch.substitutions.text_substitution.TextSubstitution object at 0x7f72314f7eb0>]' not found on the PATH
```

I have no idea what error this is.

Please help me.

thanks.

My setup is below.

Ubuntu20.04
ros2:galactic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412213/ros2-launch-gives-an-error-in-ros2_control_demos/) by [takijo](https://answers.ros.org/users/36059/takijo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2023-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I debugged the launch file and found that joint_state_publisher was the cause.
I don't know why, but uninstalling and reinstalling joint_state_publisher solved this problem.
thanks.

---

Originally posted by [takijo](https://answers.ros.org/users/36059/takijo/) with karma: 110 on 2023-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [khinggan](https://answers.ros.org/users/75010/khinggan/) on 2023-06-30**:
I still have the problem even if I uninstall and reinstall the joint_state_publisher. Could you please provide more detail about this problem and how did you debug launch file?
My setup is Ubuntu 20.04 ROS2 foxy

**Comment by [Kaushal](https://answers.ros.org/users/168032/kaushal/) on 2023-08-04**:
I am getting the same error while launching a launch file (unrelated to ros2_control). Could somebody fill me in as to why that is happening and how to solve it?