# executable '[<launch.substitutions.text_substitution.TextSubstitution>]' not found on the PATH

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, path, ros2-control

I am trying to launch the first example from the ros2 control demo package: https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/tree/humble.
I am using ROS2 humble on ubuntu 22.04. First I built every package successfully, then sourced the install/setup.bash and started the launchfile with:

```
ros2 launch ros2_control_demo_example_1 view_robot.launch.py
```

But I received the following Error.

```
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): executable '[<launch.substitutions.text_substitution.TextSubstitution object at 0x7f6a81793cd0>]' not found on the PATH
```

I did not change any code from the example. It would be nice if somebody could help me or tell me what the problem is?

Here is my Traceback:

```
[DEBUG] [launch.launch_context]: emitting event synchronously: 'launch.events.IncludeLaunchDescription'
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/user/.ros/log/date
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to DEBUG
[DEBUG] [launch]: processing event: '<launch.events.include_launch_description.IncludeLaunchDescription object at 0x7f6a8632e3e0>'
[DEBUG] [launch]: processing event: '<launch.events.include_launch_description.IncludeLaunchDescription object at 0x7f6a8232e3e0>' ✓ '<launch.event_handlers.on_include_launch_description.OnIncludeLaunchDescription object at 0x7f6a8236d8a0>'
Executing <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<LaunchService._process_one_event() done, defined at /opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py:228> exception=SubstitutionFailure("executable '[<launch.substitutions.text_substitution.TextSubstitution object at 0x7f6a81793cd0>]' not found on the PATH") created at /opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py:318> took 0.133 seconds
[DEBUG] [launch]: An exception was raised in an async action/event
[DEBUG] [launch]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 336, in run_async
    raise completed_tasks_exceptions[0]
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 230, in _process_one_event
    await self.__process_event(next_event)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 250, in __process_event
    visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(entity, self.__context))
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 38, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    sub_entities = entity.visit(context)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/action.py", line 108, in visit
    return self.execute(context)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch_ros/actions/node.py", line 490, in execute
    self._perform_substitutions(context)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch_ros/actions/node.py", line 445, in _perform_substitutions
    evaluated_parameters = evaluate_parameters(context, self.__parameters)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch_ros/utilities/evaluate_parameters.py", line 164, in evaluate_parameters
    output_params.append(evaluate_parameter_dict(context, param))
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch_ros/utilities/evaluate_parameters.py", line 72, in evaluate_parameter_dict
    evaluated_value = perform_substitutions(context, list(value))
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/utilities/perform_substitutions_impl.py", line 26, in perform_substitutions
    return ''.join([context.perform_substitution(sub) for sub in subs])
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/utilities/perform_substitutions_impl.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    return ''.join([context.perform_substitution(sub) for sub in subs])
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_context.py", line 240, in perform_substitution
    return substitution.perform(self)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/substitutions/command.py", line 94, in perform
    command_str = perform_substitutions(context, self.command)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/utilities/perform_substitutions_impl.py", line 26, in perform_substitutions
    return ''.join([context.perform_substitution(sub) for sub in subs])
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/utilities/perform_substitutions_impl.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    return ''.join([context.perform_substitution(sub) for sub in subs])
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_context.py", line 240, in perform_substitution
    return substitution.perform(self)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/substitutions/path_join_substitution.py", line 45, in perform
    performed_substitutions = [sub.perform(context) for sub in self.__substitutions]
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/substitutions/path_join_substitution.py", line 45, in <listcomp>
    performed_substitutions = [sub.perform(context) for sub in self.__substitutions]
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/substitutions/find_executable.py", line 66, in perform
    raise SubstitutionFailure("executable '{}' not found on the PATH".format(self.name))
launch.substitutions.substitution_failure.SubstitutionFailure: executable '[<launch.substitutions.text_substitution.TextSubstitution object at 0x7f6a81793cd0>]' not found on the PATH

[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): executable '[<launch.substitutions.text_substitution.TextSubstitution object at 0x7f6a81793cd0>]' not found on the PATH
[DEBUG] [launch.launch_context]: emitting event: 'launch.events.Shutdown'
[DEBUG] [launch]: processing event: '<launch.events.shutdown.Shutdown object at 0x7f6a8232e140>'
[DEBUG] [launch]: processing event: '<launch.events.shutdown.Shutdown object at 0x7f6a8232e140>' ✓ '<launch.event_handlers.on_shutdown.OnShutdown object at 0x7f6a8171cbb0>'
[DEBUG] [launch]: processing event: '<launch.events.shutdown.Shutdown object at 0x7f6a8232e140>' ✓ '<launch.event_handlers.on_shutdown.OnShutdown object at 0x7f6a8232c9a0>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that I had to install all the dependencies with rosdep. I forgot this step. Thank you @ChristophFroehlich

Follow the [tutorial](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control_demos/doc/index.html#build-from-debian-packages) on how to build the ros2 control demos:

Comment: Great to hear. Please mark an answer as solving the question (the green tick on the left side)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome at RSE.

This is maybe the same issue as described [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/issues/381). On which platform have you installed humble, from source or binary? Have you sourced your humble distro like described [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html#try-some-examples)? Are launch files as the one from the [demos](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Intermediate/Launch/Creating-Launch-Files.html) working?

Comment: Thank you.

I use Ubuntu 22.04. I installed humble from source like described here: https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html

I tried this launch file example and everything works:
https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Intermediate/Launch/Creating-Launch-Files.html

Yes I have added this line ```source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
``` in my .bashrc

Comment: Which processor architecture do you use? x86 or arm64 (like in the linked issue)

Comment: I use a x86_64 processor architecture.

Comment: Ahh and I installed humble from binary

Comment: reinstalling the ros-humble-joint-state-publisher (like https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/103002/37446) did also not solve the issue.

Comment: could you try to uncomment some parts of view_robot to narrow it down?
        joint_state_publisher_node,
        robot_state_publisher_node,
        rviz_node?

Comment: btw: Have you run rosdep, like written [here](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control_demos/doc/index.html#build-from-debian-packages)?